cannot find module export in docker
I'm running a docker application. One of my containers is running node + express + typescript and I face weird issue. I have a file that exports type and file that imports it. In my idee (vs code) there is no such error.
error: SyntaxError: The requested module './account.js' does not provide an export named 'Account'
account.ts
export type Account = {
  accountID?: string;
  name: string;
  description?: string;
  balance?: number;
  userID?: string;
};

index.ts
import { Cashflow } from "./cashflow.js";
import { Account } from "./account.js";
import { Goal } from "./goal.js";
import { createAccountAttrSchema } from "./createAccountAttrSchema.js";
import { updateAccountAttrSchema } from "./updateAccountAttrSchema.js";
import { createCashflowAttrSchema } from "./createCashflowAttrSchema.js";
import { updateCashflowAttrSchema } from "./updateCashflowAttrSchema.js";
import { createGoalAttrSchema } from "./createGoalAttrSchema.js";
import { updateGoalAttrSchema } from "./updateGoalAttrSchema.js";

export {
  Cashflow,
  Account,
  Goal,
  createAccountAttrSchema,
  updateAccountAttrSchema,
  createCashflowAttrSchema,
  updateCashflowAttrSchema,
  createGoalAttrSchema,
  updateGoalAttrSchema,
}

compose.yaml (look at the rest-api service)
services:
  rest-api:
    build: ./rest-api
    env_file: ./rest-api/.env
    volumes:
      # better dev experience
      - ./rest-api:/app/
      # to prevent dependencies errors
      - rest-api_nm:/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      # waits until db is ready
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
      # waits until keycloak is ready
      keycloak:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3000/"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
      timeout: 10s
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    env_file: ./frontend/.env
    volumes:
      # better dev experience
      - ./frontend:/app/
      # to prevent dependencies errors
      - frontend_nm:/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 4000:5173
    depends_on:
      rest-api:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
  database:
    build: ./database
    env_file: ./database/.env
    volumes:
      # for persisting db data
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # file with initial sql queries
      - ./database/init.sql:/usr/share/init.sql
    # checks if db is ready for connections
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
      timeout: 10s
  keycloak:
    build: ./keycloak
    env_file: ./keycloak/.env
    volumes:
      # for importing keycloak realm on startup
      - ./keycloak/import:/opt/keycloak/data/import
      # for storing keycloak data
      - keycloak-data:/opt/keycloak/data
    ports:
      - 5000:8080
    depends_on:
      # waits until db is ready
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    # checks if keycloak http server is running
    healthcheck:
      test: timeout 10s bash -c ':> /dev/tcp/localhost/8080'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 60s
volumes:
  rest-api_nm:
  frontend_nm:
  db-data:
  keycloak-data:


Docker file for rest-api service
FROM node:22-alpine

RUN apk add curl

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

package.json
{
  "name": "rest-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "rest api for expens",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development tsx watch src/index.ts --clear-screen=true"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/LoRd123545/expens.git"
  },
  "author": "Kamil Abbasi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/LoRd123545/expens/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/LoRd123545/expens#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/pg": "^8.11.6",
    "tsx": "^4.16.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^8.17.1",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "pg": "^8.12.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.3"
  }
}


tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext", /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "module": "NodeNext", /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "rootDir": "./src", /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext", /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    "sourceMap": true, /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    "outDir": "dist", /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "noEmitOnError": true, /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    "esModuleInterop": true, /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
      "@config/*": ["src/config/*"],
      "@middleware/*": ["src/middleware/*"],
      "@controllers/*": ["src/controllers/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["src/routes/*"],
      "@models/*": ["src/models/*"],
      "@services/*": ["src/services/*"],
      "@schemas/*": ["src/schemas/*"],
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "@types", "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./*.ts",
    "__test__"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}

I tried reinstalling node_modules, restarting app a few times.

I think since you didn't define the import with type, it doesn't remove it at build time. What happens if you use import type { Account } from "./account.js"; ?
